# SimpleRNN: why loss does not decreases when using mini-batches?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement from scratch a simple neural network framework, just to learn more about NN. I had success in implementing feed forward, fully connected neural network, but I am having some troubles with RNN. My implementation seems to work fine when training a model with stochastic gradient descent (i.e, batch_size = 1), but whenever I try to use mini-batches (batch_size greater than 1), the model seems not to work.

More precisely, my problem is the following:

I see that when using SGD the loss decreases monotonically over epochs, whereas if I use mini-batches, the loss increases greatly before starting to have a highly oscillatory behavior. I printed out the norm of the gradients over iterations and I can notice that when using mini-batches they are sometimes exploding (even if I use batch_size = 2, compared to a non-explosive behavior with batch_size = 1).

I suspect I am making some kind of mistake in the backward step but after hours of debugging, also with chatGPT, I cannot figure out the problem. Could you please help me out? I include the full code that I am using, as well as the code for a simple test.

The code for the neural network framework is as follows:

-- Sequential class: works well when I use other architecture like Dense layers, so I think this should be ok

```
### NN
import numpy as np
        
class Sequential:
    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = []

    def add(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        for layer in self.layers:
            layer.forward(inputs)
            inputs = layer.output
        return inputs

    def backward(self, d_output, learning_rate):
        for layer in reversed(self.layers):
            d_output = layer.backward(d_output, learning_rate)

    def train(self, X, y, epochs, learning_rate, batch_size, loss = MSE):

        N = X.shape[1]
        n_batches = N // batch_size
        
        
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            indices = np.random.permutation(N)
            X_shuffle = X[:,indices]
            y_shuffle = y[:,indices]
            
            for i in range(n_batches):
                X_batch = X[:,i * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size]
                y_batch = y[:,i * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size]
                predictions = self.forward(X_batch)

                d_loss = loss().loss_gradient(predictions, y_batch)
                self.backward(d_loss, learning_rate)
                
            predictions = self.forward(X)
            l = loss().loss(predictions, y)
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {l}")

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.forward(X)
```

- Cross_Entropy loss: works well in classification tasks when the output is (n, m) dimensional, where m is the number of batches.

```
import numpy as np
class Cross_Entropy:
    
    def loss(self, predictions, y):
        """ y is (n_y, m, Ty) where n_y is the dimension of the ouput, m is the number of samples, Ty is the time 
        parameter if used in a RNN."""
        
        l = -np.mean(y*np.log(predictions + 1e-8))*y.shape[0]
        return l
    def loss_gradient(self, predictions, y):
        if len(y.shape) == 2:
            grad = -y.T / (predictions.T + 1e-8) / y.shape[1]
        else:
            u = y.reshape((y.shape[1], y.shape[0], y.shape[2]))
            p = predictions.reshape((predictions.shape[1], predictions.shape[0], predictions.shape[2]))
            grad =  - (u / (p + 1e-8)) / (p.shape[0]*p.shape[2]) 
        return grad
```

- Activation functions: again, they work well when used in with Dense layers.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax

class tanh:
    def forward(self, z):
        self.input = z
        self.output = np.tanh(z)
        return self.output
    def backward(self, z = None):
        if z is None:
            derivative = 1-self.output**2
        else:
            derivative = 1-z**2
        return derivative


class Softmax:
    def forward(self, z):
        self.input = z
        self.output = softmax(z, axis = 0) #softmax for each column
        return self.output

    def backward(self, d_output, p = None):
        if p is None:
            p = self.output
        
        pp = np.einsum('ji, ki -> jki', p, p)
        
        diag = np.einsum('ji, kj -> jki',p, np.eye(p.shape[0]))
        
        return np.einsum('ij, jki -> ik', d_output, diag-pp)
```

-SimpleRNN: this is the problematic part, it implements a Simple recurrent neural network architecture, with hidden activation given by tanh, and output activation given by softmax.

```
import numpy as np
class SimpleRNN:
    def __init__(self, vocabulary_dimension, hidden_dimension, input_dim):
        #np.random.randn(units, input_size) * np.sqrt(1.0 / input_size)
        self.Waa = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(hidden_dimension, hidden_dimension))
        self.Wax = np.random.uniform(0,1, size=(hidden_dimension, input_dim))
        self.Wya = np.random.uniform(0,1, size =(vocabulary_dimension, hidden_dimension))
        self.ba = np.zeros((hidden_dimension, 1))
            

        self.by = np.zeros((vocabulary_dimension, 1))

            
        self.a0 = np.zeros((hidden_dimension, 1))
        
        self.hidden_activation = tanh()
        self.output_activation = Softmax()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        """x is (n_x, m, Tx)"""
        
        n_a = self.ba.shape[0]
        n_y = self.by.shape[0]
        m = x.shape[1]
        Tx = x.shape[2]
        
        self.input = x
        
        self.output = np.zeros((n_y, m, Tx)) 
        self.a = np.zeros((n_a, m, Tx))
        
        for t in range(Tx):
            if t == 0:
                a_prev = self.a0
            else:
                a_prev = self.a[:,:,t-1]
                
                
            zt = np.dot(self.Waa,a_prev) + np.dot(self.Wax,self.input[:,:,t]) + self.ba
            self.a[:,:,t] = self.hidden_activation.forward(zt)
            
            ut = np.dot(self.Wya,self.a[:,:,t]) + self.by
            self.output[:,:,t] = self.output_activation.forward(ut)

            
            
    def backward(self, d_output, learning_rate = 0.1):
        """
            d_output is of dimension (m, n_y, Tx)
        """
        
        n_a = self.ba.shape[0] #dimension of hidden layer
        n_y = self.output.shape[0] #output dimension
        n_x = self.input.shape[0] #input dimension
        m = self.input.shape[1] #BATCH SIZE
        Tx = self.input.shape[2] #time slices
        
        dWaa = np.zeros_like(self.Waa)
        dWax = np.zeros_like(self.Wax)
        dWya = np.zeros_like(self.Wya)
        dba = np.zeros_like(self.ba)
        dby = np.zeros_like(self.by)
        
        dx = np.zeros((m, n_x, Tx))
        
        da_next = np.zeros((m, n_a))
                
        for t in range(Tx-1, -1, -1):
            if t == 0:
                a_prev = np.ones((self.a0.shape[0], m)) * self.a0
            else:
                a_prev = self.a[:,:,t-1]

            d_output_t = d_output[:,:,t]
            
            dut = self.output_activation.backward(d_output_t, self.output[:,:,t])
            
            if t == Tx - 1:
                dat = np.dot(dut,self.Wya)
            else:
                dat = (np.dot(dut,self.Wya) + np.dot((da_next * (self.hidden_activation.backward(self.a[:,:,t+1])).T),self.Waa))
                
            dzt = dat * (self.hidden_activation.backward(self.a[:,:,t])).T
            
            da_next = dat
            
            dWaa += dzt.T @ a_prev.T
            dWax += dzt.T @ self.input[:,:,t].T
            dWya += dut.T @ self.a[:,:,t].T
            dba += dzt.sum(axis = 0, keepdims = True).reshape(-1,1)
            dby += dut.sum(axis = 0, keepdims = True).reshape(-1,1)
            
            dx[:,:,t] = np.dot(dzt, self.Wax)
            
        
        self.Waa = self.Waa - learning_rate * np.clip(dWaa, -5,5)
        self.Wax = self.Wax - learning_rate * np.clip(dWax, -5, 5)
        self.Wya = self.Wya - learning_rate * np.clip(dWya, -5, 5)
        self.ba = self.ba - learning_rate * np.clip(dba, -5, 5)
        self.by = self.by - learning_rate * np.clip(dby, -5,5)
            
        
        d_output = dx
        
        return d_output
```

To test the code, I am trying to build a character-level language model to generate new dinosaur names, given a list of names in a .txt file. Hereafter, I provide the code I am using. The file 'dinos.txt' is too large to include, but you can find the .csv version here

https://github.com/junosuarez/dinosaurs/blob/master/dinosaurs.csv

Code

```
#Read the file and convert to lowercase
data = open('dinos.txt', 'r').read().lower()

# Split data into lines (dinosaur names)
dinosaur_names = data.split('\n')

# Define the desired fixed length for names
max_name_length = 26

# Initialize a list to store modified names
padded_dinosaur_names = []

# Pad shorter names with spaces to make them equal length
for name in dinosaur_names:
    padded_name = name.ljust(max_name_length)
    padded_dinosaur_names.append(padded_name)
    
dinosaur_names = [name for name in padded_dinosaur_names]
vocab = list(set(''.join(dinosaur_names)))
char_to_index = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(vocab)}
index_to_char = {i: char for char, i in char_to_index.items()}
vocab_size = len(vocab)
max_name_length = 26

# Convert dinosaur names to sequences of indices
name_sequences = [[char_to_index[char] for char in name] for name in dinosaur_names]

# One-hot encode the sequences
one_hot_sequences = [np.eye(vocab_size)[seq] for seq in name_sequences]

# Prepare data and labels for training
X = np.zeros((vocab_size, len(dinosaur_names), max_name_length))
for name in range(len(dinosaur_names)):
    X[:,name,:] = one_hot_sequences[name].T
y = np.roll(X, -1, axis=2)  # Shift by one time step

# Create an instance of the SimpleRNN class
rnn = SimpleRNN(vocab_size, 200, vocab_size)

# Create a Sequential model and add the SimpleRNN layer
model = Sequential()
model.add(rnn)

# Train the model
epochs = 400
batch_size = 16
learning_rate = 0.01
model.train(X, y, epochs, learning_rate, batch_size, loss=Cross_Entropy)

# Generating dinosaur names
seed = "s"  # Initial seed sequence
generated_name = seed

for _ in range(max_name_length):
    seed_seq = [char_to_index[char] for char in seed]
    seed_one_hot = np.eye(vocab_size)[seed_seq]
    A = np.zeros((vocab_size, 1, len(seed_seq)))
    A[:, 0, :] = seed_one_hot.T
    prediction = model.predict(A)[:,:,-1]
    predicted_index = np.random.choice(vocab_size, p=prediction.flatten())
    predicted_char = index_to_char[predicted_index]
    if predicted_char == ' ':
        break
    generated_name += predicted_char
    seed = generated_name

print("Generated dinosaur name:", generated_name)
```

I tried changing the initializations, I tried to implement and use other optimizers like Adam, I tried to clip gradients in many different ways but I always encounter the same problem.